# what's happening with PhDs.org

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I used to check [PhDs.org](http://www.phds.org/) for info on PhD programs, but for the past few months, the site hasn't been working. Anyone know a reason for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not the administrators for the PhDs.org website; also, a website being up or down is not on-topic at this SE.

Answer (score 3):

They are not maintaining the server or the website anymore. Better to find an alternative.

Comment: any suggested alternatives?